# Entity framework mapping when foreign key column name is different

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I have a legacy table like this:

```
Country
- countryCode (PK, varchar(10), not null)
```

Now I have a new table:

```
Store
- store_id
- country_code
```

My models:

```
public class Country
{
   [Key]
   [Column("countryCode")
   public int CountryCode {get;set;}
}


public class Store
{
   [Key]
   [Column("store_id")
   public int Id {get;set;}

   [Column("country_code")]
   public int CountryCode {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to be able to do this:

```
var store = // get store

store.Country.CountryCode
```

How can I create this mapping?  **Notice that the column names are not the same (I can't change this).**

I believe I have to add this to my Store model, but how do I specificy the foreign key's seeing as they have different names?

```
public virtual CountryCode {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your database column has a type of `varchar(10)` you cannot use an `int` property in your model but you must use a `string`, no matter if the property name matches the column name or not. Also in order to be able to access the `Country` from the `Store` you need a navigation property `Store.Country`:

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [Column("countryCode", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    [Key]
    [Column("store_id")
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("country_code", TypeName = "varchar")]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Country")]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

(It's possible that the `ForeignKey` attribute is not necessary. You can try it without it. Also remove the `[Required]` attribute if the `country_code` column in table `Store` allows `NULL` values.)

You should be able now to access the `CountryCode` with for example:

```
var store = context.Stores.Find(1);
string countryCode = store.Country.CountryCode;
```

The `store.Country` navigation property will be loaded automatically via lazy loading (hence the `virtual` modifier) when you access the property.

Comment: This works thanks, BUT how come I can create a Store object, save it, even when I put in a fake countryCode.  It doesn't seem to be a foreign key relation?  It should fail to save if the PK row doesn't exist in the Country table.

Comment: @user1361315: When you use the `[ForeignKey("Country")]` attribute for EF `CountryCode` is the foreign key. If you put in an invalid code and try to save you should get a FK violation exception, assuming there is also a foreign key referential constraint in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The name has nothing to do with association (although the same name makes the db more intuitive). Through the emdx model view thing there is a form with which you can specify associations.

Here's a handy tutorial on msdn;
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx